# Online pdf viewer in Internet Explorer

Tags: android, internet-explorer, pdf

Currently my app opens online PDF files in Webview with help from Google docs, my link to the URL looks like this:

```
webV.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=mylinkto.pdf");
```

And it works fine in devices on which google chrome is default browser but not on devices on which default browser is Internet Explorer.So Is there any other url which opens pdf online in internet explorer or other browser .Please suggest.

Edit Code:

```
             try {
            mFileDescriptor = getActivity().getAssets().openFd(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Newsletter.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

            // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
         PdfRenderer mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);

            // let us just render all pages
            final int pageCount = mPdfRenderer.getPageCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                Page page = mPdfRenderer.openPage(i);
                // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.getWidth(), page.getHeight(),
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                // say we render for showing on the screen
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                // do stuff with the bitmap

                // close the page
                page.close();
            }

            // close the renderer
            mPdfRenderer.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Internet Explorer for android is available? Anyway why don't you use PdfRenderer class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html

Comment: like in htc.default browser is internet.So i am facing problem in that device

Comment: Please tell me how can i use this class

Comment: @shivanigupta have a look to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic sample project by google.

Comment: I am not getting where to pass url of pdf in this code

Comment: @AndroGeek yep. *this comment is sent from 1995*

Comment: Save the PDF file in your device then use PdfRenderer class to show it in imageView.

Comment: @shivanigupta visit example given here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example as per Anand Suggested.

Comment: ok @AnandSingh I am first downloading file from url and saving in external storage but filedescriptor is not reading the pdf.Here is my code      mFileDescriptor = getActivity().getAssets().openFd(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Newsletter.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

Comment: @shivanigupta error log?

Comment: is I am using it correctly ??Nothing shows only blank screen appears

Comment: Note: Iam not setting any imageview ??

Comment: @shivanigupta see code below.

Answer (score 0):

The PdfRenderer supports only API > 21, if you like to use free library for loading pdf files you shoul implement [this](https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js) library. There is samples around the internet of different implementations, i used it once and it worked properly.

Comment: I am getting error an't open file for reading @Vladimir Dimov'

Comment: I hope you add the needed permissions, if the error still occurs try to implement the latest version of the library from https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer . I spend +2 hours to get this working properly but was a time well spend.

Comment: yes i have added the read permission and i have updated the files in assets folder using  bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer .but still the problem exsists

Comment: Debbug your code and make sure the file path somehow looks similar to this "/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf". If is not check the slashes in the path and the way the path is build. Example : Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/test.pdf")